# User profile avatar with SAML assertion

Tags: saml-2.0

The SAML assertion from an IDP contains user profile information like name and email that can be used by the SP to set up a user profile and keep the profile attributes up to date. Is there also a possibility to provide a user avatar / profile image in the context of an SAML assertion? Either as binary / base64 stream or at least a URL? Even if not defined in the standard, is there any IDP or SP out there that supports that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard is completely open on what attributes to pass. You can any attribute in there with any data and name. So passing a URL or BASE64 data is perfectly find according to the standard. Each deployment (SP+Idp) decides on what attributes there are and what formats they should have.

That said, in the most common cases the entire SAML message is bounced over the client browser by posting the data from a hidden form field. It's not a suitable approach for a large set of binary data. Passing a URL to the image as an attribute is a perfectly fine approach to get around that. You can also look at the artifact binding, where the posted data just contains a token and the SP does a direct download of the actual SAML data from the Idp over a SOAP connection.